# Clustering Cell Tower IDs from Known location names

Tags: r, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I am new to data mining and I am trying to figure out how to cluster cell tower IDs to find its location from the known location labels (Home, Work, Elsewhere, No signal).

I have a location driven dataset of user A that contains cellID (Unique ID of detected celltowers), starttime (date & time it detected particular tower), endtime (last date & time before it connected to different celltower), placenames(user labelled place names such as home, work). There are unlabelled locations in dataset as well that are left empty by the user and I want to label these celltowers using clustering approach so that they represent as one of location names.

I am using R programming and I tried to feed complete dataset to kmeans clustering but it's resulting me with warning message which I completely dont have a clue why?

*Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

In addition: Warning message:

In kmeans(dataset, 4, 15) : NAs introduced by coercion*

Any suggestions on how can I use clustering approach for this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all the labeled and unlabeled data available at the training stage, what you are looking for is "transductive learning", which is a little different from clustering (which is "unsupervised learning").

For each cell tower you collect the average starttime, endtime and cellID. You can get lat/lng from cellIDs here: https://mozilla-ichnaea.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/search.html or http://locationapi.org/api (expensive).

This gives you 4-dimensional feature vectors for each tower, the goal is to assign a ternary labeling based on these continuous feautres:

> [avg_starttime avg_endtime lat lng] home/work/other

I don't know about R, but in python basic transductive learning is available: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/label_propagation.html#label-propagation

If you don't get good results with label propagation, and since off-the-shelf transductive learning tools are rare, you might just want to ignore some of your data during training and use more standard methods. If you ignore the unlabeled data at the start you can have an "inductive" or "supervised" learning problem (solve with an SVM). If you ignore the labels at the start you can use unsupervised learning (eg "clustering"; use kmeans or DBSCAN) and then assign labels to the clusters after clustering is done.

I don't know how you got the NaN.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I dont think i understand much about label propagation so I tried to stick with unsupervised learning, ignoring label column and use kmeans to cluster the whole dataset into 4 clusters. Now, I am confused on what basis am i suppose to label cluster 1 as either (home, work, elsewhere, nosignal) and so on for cluster 2,3,4? thank you

Comment: That's exactly the problem you would avoid with label propagation. But, now that you have clusters anyway, you should use the given labels to ensure that the clustering is homogeneous with respect to the labels. If so, then use that label for the cluster.